# How to extend CanvasRenderingContext2D (in ES6-style scripts, if possible)

Tags: javascript, canvas, ecmascript-6

I want to create a new class that extends `CanvasRenderingContext2D`. So that I can assign the user-defined attributes to the `prototype` attribute of that new class, instead of to `CanvasRenderingContext2D.attribute`. The following is the code that I intended to write:

```
class WL_CRC2D extends CanvasRenderingContext2D{
    constructor(){
        super();
    }
    setStyle(args){//...
    }
    //...
}

var ctx = new WL_CRC2D() // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

This does not work because `CanvasRenderingContext2D` prevents the `new` operator - just as the following code also throws error:

```
var ctx = new CanvasRenderingContext2D(); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal constructor
```

Then I tried to rewrite the constructor in another way:

```
 class WL_CRC2D{
    constructor(){
        let ctxTemp = Object.create(CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype);
        for (let i of Reflect.ownKeys(ctxTemp.__proto__)){
            Object.defineProperty(this.__proto__, i, Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ctxTemp.__proto__, i));
        }
    }
    setStyle(args){//...
    }
    //...
}

var ctx = new WL_CRC2D(); // fine
console.log(ctx.arc); // function arc() { [native code] }
ctx.arc(0, 0, 10, 0, 1, true); // Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

As the comments indicate, the new instance created from `WL_CRC2D` in this way cannot actually access the attributes in `WL_CRC2D.prototype`.

So is there a way to get around without tainting the system-defined class of `CanvasRenderingContext2D`? Please advise. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here's a relatively clean way to do it:

(**Note:** You can add your methods directly to `CustomC2D` instead of creating another class that extends it; I just wanted to show an example of that working.)

```js
class CustomC2D extends CanvasRenderingContext2D {
  constructor(canvas, options) {
    return Object.setPrototypeOf(canvas.getContext('2d', options), new.target.prototype)
  }
}

class MyC2D extends CustomC2D {
  get width() { return this.canvas.width }
  get height() { return this.canvas.height }
  resize(w, h) {
    this.canvas.width = w
    this.canvas.height = h
  }
  clear(color) {
    this.save()
    this.fillStyle = color
    this.fillRect(0, 0, this.width, this.height)
    this.restore()
  }
  centered_text(text) {
    this.save()
    this.textAlign = 'center'
    this.textBaseline = 
    'middle'
    this.fillText(text, this.width/2, this.height/2)
    this.restore()
  }
}

let ctx = new MyC2D(_canvas)
ctx.resize(300, 75)
ctx.clear("goldenrod")
ctx.fillStyle = "white"
ctx.font = "50px serif"
ctx.centered_text("hello, world!")
```

```html
<canvas id=_canvas></canvas>
```

**Note:** you may have heard that `Object.setPrototypeOf` is slow, but I'm pretty confident that this is just a myth/misunderstanding.

Comment: It works for me. Thank you!  
  
It is also possible to add a custom constructor:  
  
`class MyC2D extends CustomC2D { constructor(canvas, options) { super(canvas, options); ... }`

Answer (score 0):

I may have figured this out in an ugly way:

```
class WL_CanvasRenderingContext2D{
    constructor(ctx){
        this.ctx = ctx;
    }
}
(() => {
    var context = document.createElement('canvas').getContext('2d');
    for (let i of Reflect.ownKeys(Object.getPrototypeOf(ctx))){
        if (['symbol', 'constructor'].indexOf(typeof i) < 0){
            var propertyDesc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Object.getPrototypeOf(context), i);
            if (typeof context[i] != 'function'){
                [propertyDesc.get, propertyDesc.set] = [function(){return this.ctx[i]}, function(val){this.ctx[i] = val;}];
            }
            else{
                propertyDesc.value = function(...args) {this.ctx[i].apply(this.ctx, args)};
            }
            Object.defineProperty(WL_CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype, i, propertyDesc);
        }
    }
})();

var a = new WL_CanvasRenderingContext2D(ctx);
```

Please still inform me if there are any flaws with the code above. Thanks!